# Proving the convergence of $\log(n+2)/\log(n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Currently trying to prove that  $\log(n+2)/\log(n+1)$ converges to $1$ with analysis tools.

if I can prove that $\forall \varepsilon >0$, $\exists N$ such that
$$\left| \log(n+2)/\log(n+1)-1|<\varepsilon \right|$$
whenever $n\geq N$.

I tried using the integral definition of the log, along with $1=\log(n+1)/\log(n+1)$
$$
\left| \frac{\int^{n+2}_1\frac{1}{u}-\int^{n+1}_{1}\frac{1}{u}}{\int^{n+1}_1\frac{1}{u}}\right|\
$$
which I suppose simplifies to
$$
\left| \frac{\int^{n+2}_{n+1}\frac{1}{u}}{\int^{n+1}_1\frac{1}{u}}\right|\
$$
but I'm not sure where to go from here or even if this is the right direction. Or is proving that the sequence is cauchy is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

your idea can be made to work, we just need to estimate your two integrals.

Since $\frac{1}{u}$ is decreasing, your top integral

$$
\int_{n+1}^{n+2} \frac{1}{u}\ du 
\leq \left ( (n+2) - (n+1) \right )\frac{1}{n+1} 
= \frac{1}{n+1}
$$

Can you find a way to upper bound $$\frac{1}{\int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{u}\ du}?$$

Can you turn these upper bounds into an upper bound for your fraction, and show it can be made $< \epsilon$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: I think i see, similarly $\int^{n+1}_1 \frac{1}{u}\leq 1((n+1)-(1))=n$. Thus the fraction is less than $\frac{1}{(n+1)n}$ which is less than $\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$ by the archimedian property

Comment: Almost! You need to be a bit careful! In order to _upper_ bound $\frac{1}{\text{stuff}}$ we actually want to _lower_ bound $\text{stuff}$. So to upper bound $\frac{1}{\int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{u}\ du}$ we need to lower bound the integral. You have exactly the right idea, though ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove the fraction you give converges to $0$.  Note that the numerator is less than $\frac 1{n+1}$ because the integrand is less than $\frac 1{n+1}$ and the interval is $1$.  Then note the denominator (for $n \gt 3$) is greater than $1$

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use $$a_n=\frac{\log (n+2)}{\log (n+1)}$$ and compose Taylor series to get
$$a_n=1+\frac{1}{n \log (n)}-\frac{3 \log (n)+2}{2 n^2 \log ^2(n)}+O\left(\frac{1}{[n \log(n)]^3}\right)$$

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? I'm not sure I see how you got your second expression for $a_n$

Comment: $a_n=\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)+\log (n)}{\log
   \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\log (n)}$ Use Taylor series for numerator and denominator and long division.

Comment: Aaaah. Thank you! I think the word "compose" threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

Squeezing works quite well here:

\begin{eqnarray*}1
& \leq & \frac{\log (n+2)}{\log (n+1)} \\
& = & \frac{\log (n+1 + 1)}{\log (n+1)} \\
& = & \frac{\log \left((n+1)\left(1+\frac 1{n+1} \right)\right)}{\log (n+1)} \\
& = & \frac{\log (n+1)+ \log \left(1+\frac 1{n+1} \right)}{\log (n+1)} \\
& = & 1+ \frac{\log \left(1+\frac 1{n+1} \right)}{\log (n+1)} \\
& \leq & 1+ \frac{\log 2}{\log (n+1)} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, send $n\to \infty$.